# Projecting all points from one line onto another line

Tags: python, shapely

I have 2 arrays of coordinate tuples (my lines) and I am trying to project all points on line 1 onto line 2. I'd like to get the location of the nearest point on line 2 to each point in line 1, and the total distance along the line (or partial distance between the two closest points). I have a working solution using Shapely's LineStrings as seen below:

```
import shapely.geometry as geom

# Import of tuples occurs here

line_1 = geom.LineString(line_1_tuples)
line_2 = geom.LineString(line_2_tuples)

line_3 = [line_2.interpolate(line_2.project(geom.Point(x))) for x in line_1.coords]
```

This solution is slower than I'd like, are there any alternate methods to calculate the list of projected points, or a way to speed up the implementation above?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data for `line_1_tuples` and `line_2_tuples`, with expected outputs, so that this is a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the nearest point is "trivial": determine the perpendicular to `line_2` that passes through each point of `line_1`.  All of these perpendiculars have the same slope; you can do the algebra to determine the coordinates of the point on `line_2` as a function of *either* coordinate of each point on `line_1` (since the other coordinate is derived therefrom).

Put that into a function.  Put your `line_1` points into any convenient Python sequence and `apply` the function to that sequence.  `numpy` will do this for you quite efficiently.

Comment: I'm guessing that by lines the OP means a piecewise linear path in the plane, not a geometric straight line, although that is not obvious from the question.